# What is meant by run time dynamically in Decorator Design pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dynamic, runtime, decorator

While studying more than one article about Decorator Design Pattern, I noticed that all of the articles talk about Decorator enabling us to create additional features dynamically at runtime and create objects dynamically at runtime.

I totally understand the Decorator pattern, but I don't understanding what is meant by "dynamically" and if it not created in runtime, how is it created?
I need an example to illustrate.

> The problem that Decorator solves is that you can add and remove responsibilities from an object dynamically, but do it in a way so that it stays compatible with the rest of the application's code.
>
> Inheritance is the first solution that comes to mind when you need to
>   extend class behaviors. However, the inheritance is static. You can
>   not add new subclasses to a program when it is already compiled and
>   executed.[Ref](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator)

**Third question** : I need an article or description of for example this is a way object made in runtime or not and this is a way it made dynamically and this isn't

**Question 4** : How can I distinguish between that this code is made in runtime or not and dynamically or not?

Refs :

1. [Tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-decorator-pattern--cms-22641)
2. [Laracsts video](https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php/episodes/1)
3. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can answer your 4 questions just by showing the different between Decoration (Dynamic) and Inheritance (Static).

**Inheritance (Static) = less flexible**. Let's say you have class `B` that inherits class `A`. Then at run-time, *every* instance of class `B` will use the code of class `A`. No way to change this when the program is running. To change it you have to do at compile-time.

**Decoration (Dynamic) = more flexible**. Class `B` does not treat class `A` as parent but instead treats `A` as a friend. This is often achieved by using a technique called *Dependency Injection*: constructor of `B` receives an object belonging to type `A`. When you want to create an instance of `B`, you have to first create an instance of `A` or of whatever subclass of `A`, and pass it to the constructor of `B`. This design is more flexible but also more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that the Pattern is `Decorator` not `Decoration`, and I have edited the text accordingly.

Several of the classic Patterns, find better ways than inheritance to change how classes behave. Examples are `Strategy`, `Composite`, `Chain of Responsibility` and of course `Decorator`. In fact 3 of the above work by making linked lists of objects, that cooperate to do something "complicated" that would be difficult an inefficient using inheritance. Using the patterns you can compose collections of objects to execute complex behaviour at runtime by joining/injecting multiple objects.

The point of all this is that you may not know at compile time what complex behaviour is needed, and it may depend on inputs and configurations etc. This requires a flexible way to instantiate and combine classes at runtime, in a way that would be virtually impossible at compile time.

The authors of the quotes in your question, were expressing the same thing. ie That inheritance is just not a flexible way to build complex behavior that may not be known until runtime.